# Activity instance fields null after returning from child activity

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I'm struggling with an Android activity lifecycle issue: When I return to an activity from its child activity, all the instance variables are null, even though they should have been initialized in the onCreate() method of the activity. As you can see below, the SignSearchActivity works fine as long as I stay on the activity. Orientation changes are no problem. As soon as I navigate to the child activity SignSearch_Video_Activity and navigate back up again, a NullPointerException is thrown in the SignSearchActivity.onStart() method. As you can see from the log output the SignSearchActivity.onCreate() method *is* actually called before the onStart() method. I've had a very similar issue in the SignSearchActivity.onPostExecute() method, but I was able to find a workaround for that (see FIXME code below). Now, I'm really stuck.

Any help very much appreciated.

Best

Matthias

Searching for a string triggers normal lifecycle flow (instance hashCode at the end)

```
03-20 17:34:25.187 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignBrowserUIFragment: onPause
03-20 17:34:25.201 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onCreate() 81236595
03-20 17:34:25.250 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: setupRecyclerView() 81236595
03-20 17:34:25.251 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: setupSupportActionBar() 81236595
03-20 17:34:25.252 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: initSignSearchTaskFragment() 81236595
03-20 17:34:25.253 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onStart() 81236595
03-20 17:34:25.254 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onPreExecute 81236595
03-20 17:34:25.257 5980-6295/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignDAO: Opening database.
03-20 17:34:25.261 5980-6295/de.foo.bar.baz I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database signs.db
03-20 17:34:25.262 5980-6295/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignDAO: Reading signs with name_locale_de like: ma
03-20 17:34:25.264 5980-6295/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignDAO: Closing database.
03-20 17:34:25.311 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onCreateOptionsMenu()81236595
03-20 17:34:25.326 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onPostExecute 81236595
03-20 17:34:25.382 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/MainActivity: onSaveInstance
03-20 17:34:25.390 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignBrowserUIFragment: onSaveInstance
```

Orientation change will saveInstance and create a new instance of SignSearchActivity (see hashCode at the end)

```
03-20 17:36:21.849 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onPause()81236595
>> 03-20 17:36:21.849 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onSaveInstanceState() 81236595
03-20 17:36:21.862 5980-6039/de.foo.bar.baz E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb87d8f40
>> 03-20 17:36:21.898 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onCreate() 169372560 
03-20 17:36:21.914 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: setupRecyclerView() 169372560
03-20 17:36:21.914 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: setupSupportActionBar() 169372560
03-20 17:36:21.933 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onStart() 169372560
03-20 17:36:21.933 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onPreExecute 169372560
03-20 17:36:21.939 5980-6296/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignDAO: Opening database.
03-20 17:36:21.945 5980-6296/de.foo.bar.baz I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database signs.db
03-20 17:36:21.946 5980-6296/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignDAO: Reading signs with name_locale_de like: ma
03-20 17:36:21.947 5980-6296/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignDAO: Closing database.
03-20 17:36:21.973 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onCreateOptionsMenu()169372560
03-20 17:36:21.994 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onPostExecute 169372560
```

Clicking on a sign will also saveInstance

```
03-20 17:56:54.415 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onTxtSignNameClicked() 169372560
03-20 17:56:54.456 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onPause()169372560
03-20 17:56:54.472 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchVideoActivity: onCreate()24174267
03-20 17:56:54.509 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignVideoUIFragment: onCreateView
03-20 17:56:54.644 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignVideoUIFragment: onActivityCreated
03-20 17:56:55.129 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
>> 03-20 17:56:55.182 5980-5980/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onSaveInstanceState() 169372560
03-20 17:56:55.614 5980-6001/de.foo.bar.baz W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
```

Clicking on homeAsUpIndicator will cause NullPointerException in SignSearchActitivity

```
03-20 18:02:40.552 1625-1625/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchVideoActivity: onPause()24174267
03-20 18:02:40.635 1625-1625/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onCreate() 188070473
03-20 18:02:40.654 1625-1625/de.foo.bar.baz D/SignSearchActivity: onStart() 188070473
03-20 18:02:40.659 1625-1625/de.foo.bar.baz D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-20 18:02:40.672 1625-1625/de.foo.bar.baz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                 Process: de.foo.bar.baz, PID: 1625
                                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.foo.bar.baz/de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.search.SignSearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.search.SignSearchTaskFragment.isRunning()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.search.SignSearchTaskFragment.isRunning()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                     at de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.search.SignSearchActivity.onStart(SignSearchActivity.java:91)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1260)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6261)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

SignSearchActivity

```
package de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.search;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import de.foo.bar.baz.R;
import de.foo.bar.baz.database.Sign;
import de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.search.video.SignSearchVideoActivity;
import de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.video.SignVideoUIFragment;

public class SignSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SignSearchTaskFragment.TaskCallbacks {

    private static final java.lang.String KEY_QUERY = "sign_browser_search_query";
    private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "sign_browser_search_task_fragment";
    private static final String TAG = SignSearchActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private SignSearchTaskFragment signSearchTaskFragment;
    private String query = StringUtils.EMPTY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() " + this.hashCode());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            this.query = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_QUERY);
        } else {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (!(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))) {
                return;
            }
            this.query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        }
        setupRecyclerView();
        setupSupportActionBar();
        this.signSearchTaskFragment = (SignSearchTaskFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);
        if (null == this.signSearchTaskFragment) {
            initSignSearchTaskFragment();
        }
    }

    private void initSignSearchTaskFragment() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initSignSearchTaskFragment() " + this.hashCode());
        this.signSearchTaskFragment = new SignSearchTaskFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(signSearchTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupRecyclerView() " + this.hashCode());
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.signSearchRecyclerView);
//        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); // performance fix
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SignSearchAdapter(new ArrayList<Sign>(), this));
    }

    private void setupSupportActionBar() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupSupportActionBar() " + this.hashCode());
        final ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (null == supportActionBar) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SupportActionBar is null. Should have been set in " +
                    "onCreate().");
        }
        supportActionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.search_results) + StringUtils.SPACE + this.query);
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart() " + this.hashCode());
        super.onStart();
//        if (null != this.signSearchTaskFragment) {
            if (!this.signSearchTaskFragment.isRunning()) {
                this.signSearchTaskFragment.start(this, query);
            }
//        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause()" + this.hashCode());
        super.onPause();
        if (signSearchTaskFragment.isRunning()) {
            this.signSearchTaskFragment.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu()" + this.hashCode());
        final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_sign_browser_search, menu);
        final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState() " + this.hashCode());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_QUERY, this.query);
    }

    public void onTxtSignNameClicked(Sign sign) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTxtSignNameClicked() " + this.hashCode());
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignSearchVideoActivity.class);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(SignVideoUIFragment.SIGN_TO_SHOW, sign);
        intent.putExtra(SignSearchVideoActivity.EXTRA, bundle);
        startActivity(intent);

//        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, LevelOneActivity.class);
//        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//        bundle.putString(LevelOneActivity.FRAGMENT_TO_SHOW, SignVideoUIFragment.class.getSimpleName());
//        bundle.putParcelable(SignVideoUIFragment.SIGN_TO_SHOW, sign);
//        intent.putExtra(LevelOneActivity.EXTRA, bundle);
//        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute " + this.hashCode());
        /*no-op*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate " + this.hashCode());
        /*no-op*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled " + this.hashCode());
        /*no-op*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(List<Sign> result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute " + this.hashCode());
        // FIXME: After savedInstance has been called, this.recyclerview is null here, despite being
        // FIXME: set in the onCreated() method. Therefore a findViewById is necessary.
        final RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.signSearchRecyclerView);
        if (null == mRecyclerView) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("mRecyclerView is null");
        }
        mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(new SignSearchAdapter(result, this), false);
    }
}
```

SignSearch_Video_Activity

```
package de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.search.video;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import de.foo.bar.baz.R;
import de.foo.bar.baz.sign_browser.video.SignVideoUIFragment;

public class SignSearchVideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = SignSearchVideoActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String EXTRA = "extra";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()" + this.hashCode());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_video_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (null != getSupportActionBar()) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(StringUtils.EMPTY);
        }
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(EXTRA);
        if (null == bundle) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The bundle supplied to the activity is null");
        }
        final Parcelable sign = bundle.getParcelable(SignVideoUIFragment.SIGN_TO_SHOW);
        final SignVideoUIFragment signVideoUIFragment = new SignVideoUIFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(SignVideoUIFragment.SIGN_TO_SHOW, sign);
        signVideoUIFragment.setArguments(args);
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.searchVideoActivityContentFrame, signVideoUIFragment, "SIGN_VIDEO_TAG");
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause()" + this.hashCode());
        super.onPause();
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself:

The problem was that even though the onCreate() method of the SignSearchActivity was executed, vital parts of it were not. This was due to the fact that the child activity did not call the SignSearchActivity (which is backing a SearchView) with the right kind of intent.

So this code

```
 if (!(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))) {
                return;
            }
```

meant that the SignSearch.onCreate() method returned when it wasn't supposed to.

Now, the SignSearchActivity passes the query to the SignSearchVideoActivity as an intent extra. When the SignSearchVideoActivity navigates back up to the SignSearchActivity, it passes the original query back again.

Modified SignSearchActivity.onCreate() method.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() " + this.hashCode());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            this.query = savedInstanceState.getString(QUERY);
        } else {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            this.query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Validate.notNull(this.query, "The query supplied to this activity is null!");
        }
        setupRecyclerView();
        setupSupportActionBar();
        this.signSearchTaskFragment = (SignSearchTaskFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);
        if (null == this.signSearchTaskFragment) {
            initSignSearchTaskFragment();
        }
    }
```

New SignSearchVideoActivity.onOptionItemsSelected() method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected() " + this.hashCode());
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                final Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
                upIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, this.originalQuery);
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```